# Integrate Gpay to Serrvicenow

Tags: javascript, servicenow, google-pay

I would like to know about implementation of integration between servicenow and Gpay.

the idea would be like showing the Gpay button as a widget on the service portal page.

Comment: can you please follow this link:
https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_article&sys_id=f9b020661b0394103222ea89bd4bcb99

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ServiceNow, but it sounds like it should be [possible](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/orlando-servicenow-platform/page/build/service-portal/concept/service-portal-widgets.html) to achieve this with a widget.

As to whether there are any existing widgets that do this, I haven't been able to find one with a quick search.